# 2020 explorer will not fill up

Tags: ford, gasoline, explorer

My 2020 ford explorer will not let me fill up. I tried to fill up yesterday and it only let me put 0.336 gallons in and it started spitting it back out. I only have between three quarter and a half in it, I'm scared to try and put anymore in it, help

Comment: Has the tank collapsed? can happen if the air vent is blocked. But as it is new, you should just take it in under warranty - unless you want to void the warranty by playing with it.

Answer (score 14):

Are you sure the gas station was open?  I recently had the same problem and found that the lights were fully on at the station, the digital readouts on the pumps were glowing, but the place was actually closed and the station owner disabled the pumps.  Many stations are closing earlier than expected due to COVID-19.  If you are using a credit card to pay at the pump, make sure its authorization wasn't rejected.

Did you try a different pump, or perhaps a different gas station altogether?  I've ocasssionally had weird back pressure on a filling nozzle.

Your Explorer has a "capless" filling system.  Be sure you are inserting the gas nozzle fully, because it must get past two, spring-loaded rubber flaps inside the neck of your gas tank.  See [this video](https://owner.ford.com/support/how-tos/exterior/equipment/how-the-easy-capless-fuel-filler-works.html#) from Ford for a further explanation.  Also, try changing the angle of the nozzle a bit, re-inserting it up or down, and try to fill again.

If this really is a brand new vehicle, why not take it to a Ford dealership under warranty?  There really shouldn't be anything else for you to do.